# Jquery shorten a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this simple html structure

```
<div id="img1" class="red">
  <img src="#">
</div>
<div id="img2" class="red">
  <img src="#">
</div>
<article>
  <div class="text">
    <h2><a href="" id="link1">This</a> is just a try to understand if i'm able to use this fukking stuff or i will <a href="" id="link2">suck</a> this time like many others</h2>
  </div>
</article>
```

And i'm trying to retrieve some information about my link position to pass that value to the image, in order to change their initial position in some absolute way.

This is the jQuery that ACTUALLY WORK for me.

```
function positioning() {
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
  var top1 = $("#link1").offset().top - number;
  var top2 = $("#link2").offset().top - number;

  var left1 = $("#link1").offset().left;
  var left2 = $("#link2").offset().left;

  var right1 = $(window).width() - (left1 + $("#link1").width());
  var right2 = $(window).width() - (left2 + $("#link2").width());

  if (left1 > ($(window).width()/2)) {
    $("#img1").css({"top": top1, "right": right1 - number});
  } else {
    $("#img1").css({"top": top1, "left": left1 - number});
  };

  if (left2 > ($(window).width()/2)) {
    $("#img2").css({"top": top2, "right": right2 - number});
  } else {
    $("#img2").css({"top": top2, "left": left2 - number});
  };
};
```

BUT i don't want to repeat all this stuff for all my links and image because i will have a lot more. So, i'm thinking to some way to do this but it doesn't work. This is the code i've produced. Could somebody help me understand which are my errors?

```
var n = $("a[id*='link']").length;
var top = [];
var left = [];
var right = [];
var valore;

function positioning() {
  $("a[id*='link']").each(function() {

    for(var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
      top.push(this.offset().top);
      left.push(this.offset().left);
      right.push($(window).width() - (left[i] + this));
    };
  });

  $("a[id*='img']").each(function() {
    valore = this.id.slice(-1);
    $(this).css("top", top[valore]);

   if (left[valore] > ($(window).width()/2)) {
     $(this).css("right", right[valore]);
   } else {
     $(this).css("left", left[valore]);
   };

  });

};
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
 at $(this).css(“top”, top[valore]);
Uncaught ReferenceError: positioning is not defined
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What doesn't work? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Unsure if this is an issue, `$(this).css(“top”, top[valore]);` <- Those are fancy quotes.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL ` at `$(this).css(“top”, top[valore]);` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: positioning is not defined `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a string `top` quoted with the wrong quotes `“` `”` they should both be `"`.

Replace

```
$(this).css(“top”, top[valore]);
```

with

```
$(this).css("top", top[valore]);
```

As for your complete function, you can try this:

```
function positioning() {
    var window_width = $(window).width();
    $("[id^='link']").each(function(index, link) {
        var $link = $(link);
        var top = $link.offset().top;
        var left = $link.offset().left;
        var right =  window_width - (left + $link.width());

        var num = link.id.replace("link", "");
        var $img = $("#img"+num);
        $img.css("top", top);
        if (left > window_width/2) {
            $img.css("right", right);
        } else {
            $img.css("left", left);
        };
    });
}
```

I simplified it so, it only uses a single loop, and doesn't need arrays to store position data.

Comment: ok! that was wrong :) thanks. but it doesn't work eitherway. It only takes just 1 position (and wrong) :(

Comment: you take from each link their position but if you dont store them in an array how can you call the top1 or top2 when you have to assign the .css() ?

Comment: You assign the CSS immediately, before you go to the next link.